# Minimal Inform6 code to support <action> syntax

Tags: interactive-fiction

Without using any of the standard Inform libraries, what is the minimal amount of code / infrastructure needed to support the `<action>` syntax?

What I tried is

```
Verb 'foo' * -> Foo;

[ FooSub;
    "Hello from FooSub";
];

[ Main;
  <foo>;
];
```

I expected this to print `Hello from FooSub` when run; however, the output I get is

```
Action <0 0 0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By bisecting the standard `parserm.h` file, I've found that the secret sauce is the platform function `R_Process`. By adding the following implementation of it to my code:

```
[ R_Process a;
    indirect(#actions_table-->a);
];
```

I got `<foo>` to work.